# How to add ViewModel to a project which uses ViewPager and Tablayout?

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-viewmodel

Hello i am new in Android Development so maybe this question can be weird for you.

I have a class named **IdentityCardInfo** which has variables. And I am getting this variables in **InfoFragment**.

From InfoFragment I want to show these variables in a **ResultsFragment** wihch has 3 tabs with tablayout.

I want to use **ViewModel** to pass data to tablayouts but I don't know how to use I've searched but get stuck.

Here is code for IdentityCardInfo class:

```
class IdentityCardInfo {

    companion object AppConstant{
        const val serieNo ="67G74444"
        const val validDate = "01/01/2022"
        const val dateOfBirth = "10/08/1998"
        const val fullName = "Muhittin KAYA"
        const val identityNo: Long = 11111111111
        const val gender = "MALE"
        const val nationality = "TUR"
    }
}
```

Here is code for InfoFragment:

```
class InfoFragment : BaseFragment() {

    lateinit var navController: NavController

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "Info Fragment"
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        button_info_idcard.setOnClickListener {
            //start OcrActivity
            val intent = Intent(activity, OcrActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
        }

        imagebutton_info_settings.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_infoFragment_to_settingsFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i("Muhittin", "onActivityResult()")

        if (requestCode == 101) {
            val message = data?.getStringExtra("TEST_TEXT")
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val serieNo = IdentityCardInfo.serieNo
            val validDate = IdentityCardInfo.validDate
            val dateOfBirth = IdentityCardInfo.dateOfBirth
            val fullname = IdentityCardInfo.fullName
            val gender = IdentityCardInfo.gender
            val identityNo = IdentityCardInfo.identityNo
            val nationality = IdentityCardInfo.nationality

            val bundle = bundleOf(
                "TEST_TEXT" to message,
                "SERIE_NO" to serieNo,
                "VALID_DATE" to validDate,
                "DOB" to dateOfBirth,
                "FULL_NAME" to fullname,
                "GENDER" to gender,
                "IDENTITY_NO" to identityNo,
                "NATIONALITY" to nationality
            )
            navController.navigate(
                R.id.action_infoFragment_to_detailFragment,
                bundle
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is for ResultsFragment: (I don't add tablayout code and viewpager code)

```
class ResultsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        val tabLayout: TabLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_results)

        tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
        val tabTitles = arrayOf(
            resources.getString(R.string.result_tab1_name),
            resources.getString(R.string.result_tab2_name),
            resources.getString(R.string.result_tab3_name)
        )

        val viewPager: ViewPager = requireView().findViewById(R.id.viewpager_results)
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        val adapter = PagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabTitles)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }

}
```

Comment: You can create interface methods and pass data in it. And on the receiving class you can implement its override methods and get you data. For better understanding refer [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/passing-data-between-fragments-on-android-using-viewmodel-d47fa6773f9c) link

Comment: Happy to help. Enjoy coding:)

Comment: Still if you don't understand then tell me I'll put code here

Comment: Can you put it please :) Because I am thinking but can't resolve how to put the data and where?

Comment: Sure give me some time I'll put it here

Comment: I've posted my answer please refer it, upvote and Click on tick mark if it helps you.

Comment: Again thank you so much Mashuk, you helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@muhittin kaya Refer below code to resolve your issue

**InfoFragment**

```
class InfoFragment : BaseFragment() {

    lateinit var navController: NavController

    // Initialize your variable
    lateinit var infoFragmentInterface: InfoFragmentDataInterface

    // If you get initialization exception then uncomment below line and comment above line
    //private var  infoFragmentInterface: InfoFragmentDataInterface? = null


    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "Info Fragment"
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        button_info_idcard.setOnClickListener {
            //start OcrActivity
            val intent = Intent(activity, OcrActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
        }

        imagebutton_info_settings.setOnClickListener {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_infoFragment_to_settingsFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i("Muhittin", "onActivityResult()")

        if (requestCode == 101) {
            val message = data?.getStringExtra("TEST_TEXT")
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val serieNo = IdentityCardInfo.serieNo
            val validDate = IdentityCardInfo.validDate
            val dateOfBirth = IdentityCardInfo.dateOfBirth
            val fullname = IdentityCardInfo.fullName
            val gender = IdentityCardInfo.gender
            val identityNo = IdentityCardInfo.identityNo
            val nationality = IdentityCardInfo.nationality

            val bundle = bundleOf(
                "TEST_TEXT" to message,
                "SERIE_NO" to serieNo,
                "VALID_DATE" to validDate,
                "DOB" to dateOfBirth,
                "FULL_NAME" to fullname,
                "GENDER" to gender,
                "IDENTITY_NO" to identityNo,
                "NATIONALITY" to nationality
            )

            //Add This line for passing your data
            //You can also pass string data here
            infoFragmentInterface.getInfoFragmentData(bundle)

            navController.navigate(
                R.id.action_infoFragment_to_detailFragment,
                bundle
            )
        }
    }
}

// Create this interface to pass your data
interface InfoFragmentDataInterface {
    fun getInfoFragmentData(bundle: Any)
}
```

**ResultsFragment**

```
class ResultsFragment : Fragment(), InfoFragmentDataInterface {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        val tabLayout: TabLayout = requireView().findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_results)

        tabLayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL
        val tabTitles = arrayOf(
            resources.getString(R.string.result_tab1_name),
            resources.getString(R.string.result_tab2_name),
            resources.getString(R.string.result_tab3_name)
        )

        val viewPager: ViewPager = requireView().findViewById(R.id.viewpager_results)
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        val adapter = PagerAdapter(fragmentManager, tabTitles)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }

    override fun getInfoFragmentData(bundle: Any) {
        // You'll get your Bundle data here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `ViewModel`s to pass data between fragments **in the same activity**, [here's the Android documentation about it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). It lets the fragments access a shared object without needing to know about each other, or communicate through the activity (with a bunch of code just to enable that communication)

You'd basically do something like this:

```
// create a ViewModel that holds the data you want to share
class IdentityCardViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val identityInfo = MutableLiveData<IdentityCardInfo>()

    fun setInfo(info: IdentityCardInfo) {
        identityInfo.value = info
    }
}
```

Then each fragment would grab a copy of *the same ViewModel instance* by doing:

```
// Get a reference to the IdentityCardViewModel created and held by the activity
private val model: IdentityCardViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

and then `InfoFragment` can set the data with `model.setInfo(yourIdentityCardInfo)`. `ResultsFragment`can observe this data and do something whenever it sees a new value:

```
model.identityInfo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<IdentityCardInfo> { info ->
        // Do whatever you need with the updated info, like displaying it
    })
```